# Urdu/Arabic text recovery

Tags: windows, text, encoding, character-encoding

First of all Pardon for posting this question here, but I have no Idea where to post this question and I REALLY in need of a help.

I had created a file in notepad++, converted its encoding to Characterset->Arabic->ISO-8859-6

and copied and pasted some text in Arabic then closed the file.

but when I reopened it, all the text had converted into some wierd characters, something like:

Ê?æ??? åèÇÕäÇÊ? æØÇå¬

I also opened the file with microsoft word, and choose the encoding Arabic (Windows) , but it also didnt work.

I really need this data back. I would be really grateful if anyone could tell me how to get proper text back.

Comment: on notepad++ when you save the file it does not save the encoding, so when you open it tries to open with the default encoding. Try using MS word and save the desired encoding with the help of this link http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-HA010121249.aspx

Comment: @AI25 tried MS word, wordpad too but no use.please if you couls tell anyother solution it is really urgent.Thanks